# How to prevent Command Promt from closing when I turn it off in Python?

Tags: python, command-prompt

I am very new to python. I have a little program and I want it run in the following order :

- First I set a method time.sleep(10) within code to suspends execution for the 10 seconds in my test file.
- I run my test file by command prompt.
- While the program is performing a suspension of 10 seconds, suddenly I click the X close button in the top-right corner of the window, the program will not immediately shut down but it will run command `print('Close terminal event detected.')` and delay about 1 second by `time.sleep(1)` before it shuts off.

I wrote the code below but I'm still stuck. Would someone please tell me how to do it? Thank you.

```
import time
import os

time.sleep(10)

# If the terminal is closed while time.sleep(10) is running, the program will print the following line and run time.sleep(1) before exiting
print('Close terminal event detected.')

time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define ***on_exit*** function and set it on *win32api* as **True**

```
import time
def on_exit(sig, func=None):
    print('Close terminal event detected.')
    time.sleep(1)

import win32api
win32api.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(on_exit, True)

print ("Executing")
time.sleep(10)
```

Executing will be printed and control goes to time.sleep(10)
As and ***when you hit exit***, the event is detected and ***on_exit*** function is called.
Hence it will print ***Close terminal event detected.*** and then wait for a second and closes the window.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks very much. I tried it but it only works on VScode terminal. It does not work on Cmd.

Comment: If you are using Unix, try :
import signal
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, on_exit)

Comment: Thanks, but 2 parameters ```sig```, ```func``` in ```def on_exit``` is used for what ?